# Checked radio buttons misaligned when using custom CSS

Tags: css, sass, radio-button

I'm implementing some custom styles for radio buttons and am having problems trying to perfectly center the checked buttons. When I paste the exact same code into JS Fiddle, things work perfectly. Yet in my web app, they are each off centered (in their own way) like the image below, despite having the same classnames, positioning, etc:

Image link: [Off-centered checked radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euW86.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="RadioStyled">
  <label class="control-label">
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="radio"
      ref="check1"
    >
    <span class="radio-styled checked"></span>
    <span class="label-text">Australia</span>
  </label>
  <div class="RadioStyled">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="RadioStyled">
  <label class="control-label">
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="radio"
      ref="check2"
    >
    <span class="radio-styled checked"></span>
    <span class="label-text">Belgium</span>
  </label>
  <div class="RadioStyled">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="RadioStyled">
  <label class="control-label">
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="radio"
      ref="check3"
    >
    <span class="radio-styled checked"></span>
    <span class="label-text">United Kingdom</span>
  </label>
  <div class="RadioStyled">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="some-other-element">
  <div class="RadioStyled">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="radio"
        ref="check3"
      >
      <span class="radio-styled checked"></span>
      <span class="label-text">New Zealand</span>
    </label>
    <div class="RadioStyled">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="RadioStyled">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="radio"
        ref="check3"
      >
      <span class="radio-styled checked"></span>
      <span class="label-text">Canada</span>
    </label>
    <div class="RadioStyled">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS / SCSS:

```
.RadioStyled {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
    label.control-label {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        line-height: 24px;
        .label-text {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: black;
            padding-left: 6px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
            display: none;
        }
        .radio-styled {
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 20px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 20px;
        }
        .radio-styled.checked {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .radio-styled.checked::before {
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            // margin: -1px -1px;
            transform: scale(0.5);
            position: relative;
            top: -1px;
            right: 1px;
        }
    }
}

.some-other-element {
  padding-left: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/davely/pen/grZWQP)

Any idea what's happening here that makes each checked radio button seem to have a different position? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a CodePen link to your question, because your CSS/Sass is ignored by JSFiddle.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Updated! http://codepen.io/davely/pen/grZWQP

Comment: Thanks Dave! In what browser do you see this behaviour?

Comment: I'm seeing it happen in Chrome v50, Safari v9.1, and Firefox v42 (all desktop). Interestingly, not seeing it inside mobile Safari on iOS.

Comment: I don't see weird results: http://i.imgur.com/qw6Pakq.png (I unchecked Belgium via the code). Chrome latest version.